# Forge -> Inventor Configurator activity fails before it downloads - Used to work before upgrade to Inventor 2023 Engine

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I have just updated my working configurator model from Inventor 2022 to Inventor 2023, and therefore re-built the plugins using the new local Inventor 2023 bin directory, uploaded the plugins to new versions of AppBundles that I created.

I then updated the relevant activity to show the engine selection as Inventor 2023, but using the exact same procedure as before for submitting a WorkItem - which worked with Inventor 2022 setup - does not work.

There is a failure to even download the first InventorDoc...

Could anybody suggest anything?

Output from the log file as follows:

```
[05/17/2022 11:35:24] Folder "T:\Aces\Jobs\14cc7d89601542d6bd93e83a9ab842dd\unzippedIam" has been created.
[05/17/2022 11:35:25] Starting work item 14cc7d89601542d6bd93e83a9ab842dd
[05/17/2022 11:35:25] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase InProgress of job.
[05/17/2022 11:35:25] Job finished with result FailedEnvironmentSetup
[05/17/2022 11:35:25] Job Status:
  "status": "failedDownload"
```

Comment: 2023 is not working yet 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72276499/autodesk-inventor-2023-failedenvironmentsetup

Comment: It's supposed to have gone live now! Please give it a try. It does not include RFA export though.

Comment: Hi @AdamNagy, yes it is working just perfectly. Thanks Team!