# Autodesk.Inventor_2023 FailedEnvironmentSetup

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

My design automation workitem for Inventor engine 2023 is running into error FailedEnvironmentSetup with the Job Status error as "status": "failedDownload". I am wondering, is this because currently the engine for 2023 is not working yet.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the reason. We are actively working on the Inventor 2023 support, which should be active soon.

Comment: Great, Thanks! Since our customer are asking about the 2023 support, I would appreciate if you can provide an estimation of how long would it be till it is supported.

Comment: Inventor 2023 support is now live. Please note that the export of the Inventor documents to Revit (RFA) is still not working on 2023 version.

Comment: Noted. For Inventor I don't see the above error anymore and the code is getting executed till the end.